# Extension shows in phpinfo(), but extension_loaded() fails

Tags: php, mcrypt

I'm trying to get mcrypt php extension to work.

Getting the following error when installing [tinyissue](https://github.com/mikelbring/tinyissue):

```
Installation

Please install all required extensions
mcrypt extension not found.
```

The extension shows fine in `phpinfo()`, but the `extension_loaded('mcrypt')` test by tinyissue is failing.

This is on ubuntu, so mcrypt was installed using `apt-get install php5-mcrypt` and `/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` exists.

Comment: Having the exact same problem in 2019, with the `gmp` extension.